# Monitor and Synchronized keyword in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

So I'm having problems understanding the distinction between a Java Monitor and the synchronized keyword.

I read that in Java, every class is basically a monitor. What is the purpose of declaring it as

```
monitor BankAccount{
   double balance;    

   public void withdraw(){}

   public void deposit(){}

}
```

Will every method of this class be synchronized or do I need to specify the keyword?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: this isn't a valid class declaration as monitor isn't a keyword in Java.

Comment: Objects have monitors, but class are not monitors. If want methods to be synchronised, you have to use the keyword on each one.  Note: to lock two Accounts you have to be careful the order you do so to avoid a deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A monitor may be associated with every object instance in Java. This includes `Class` objects. There is, however, no keyword `monitor`. The monitor is synchronized upon when methods are invoked on an object that are declared `synchronized` or when an explicit `synchronized` block is used. Static methods synchronize on the monitor associated with the `Class` object representing the class type.

Answer (score 2):

`monitor` isn't a keyword.  Nothing is synchronized by default.  You need the `synchronized` keyword on a method for it to be synchronized (or to use some other locking mechanism explicitly, but it won't happen automatically).